# Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd

Tags: c

I am currently working on a program to solve the knapsack problem and i had to use pointers to a matrix. After using a pseudocode i was given at school i keep receiving a segmentation fault and according to valgrind this is the reason:

```
1 errors in context 1 of 2:
==10545== Invalid write of size 4
==10545==    at 0x4009C3: DP (dp.c:70)
==10545==    by 0x400914: main (dp.c:39)
==10545==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==10545==
==10545==
=
=10545== 1 errors in context 2 of 2:
==10545== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==10545==    at 0x4009C3: DP (dp.c:70)
==10545==    by 0x400914: main (dp.c:39)
==10545==
```

i have tried to use past answers to solve the problem but i can't seem to figure it out. Other people at school have did the exact same thing and they don't seem to receive this issue. Is there any mistake i don't seem to see or to realise in the code?

```
 int **V, **keep;  // 2d arrays for use in the dynamic programming solution
 // keep[][] and V[][] are both of size (n+1)*(W+1)

 int i, w, K;

 // Dynamically allocate memory for variables V and keep
 V = (int**)malloc((n+1) * (W+1) * sizeof(int*));
 keep = (int**)malloc((n+1) * (W+1) * sizeof(int*));

 //  set the values of the zeroth row of the partial solutions table to zero
 for (w = 0; w <= W; w++)
 {
    V[0][w] = 0;
 }

 // main dynamic programming loops , adding one item at a time and looping          through weights from 0 to W
 for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
   for (w = 0; w <= W; w++)
     if ((wv[i] <= w) && (v[i] + V[i-1][w - wv[i]] > V[i - 1][w]))
     {
       V[i][w] = v[i] + V[i-1][w-wv[i]];
       keep[i][w] = 1;
     }

     else
     {
       V[i][w] = V[i-1][w];
       keep[i][w] = 0;
     } 

 K = W;
 for (i = n; i >= 1; i--);
 {
   if (keep[i][K] == 1)
   {
     printf("%d\n", i);
     K = K - wv[i];
   }
 } 
 return V[n][W];
 }
```

Comment: `NULL` pointer dereference.

Answer (score 1):

```
V = (int**)malloc((n+1) * (W+1) * sizeof(int*));
...
for (w = 0; w <= W; w++)
{
  V[0][w] = 0;
}
```

The size supplied in your `malloc` call makes no sense. And you never initialized `V[0]` (or any `V[i]` for that matter). It contains a garbage value. Yet you attempt to access `V[0][w]` (and `V[i][w]` later). This is undefined behavior.

If you intend to use your `V` as a 2D array, [allocate it properly](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/dynmuldimary.html) first.